# Laravel 5.4 Does not return to page after updating database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

when i updated database, my return page doesnt open.. it jamming on transaction page..

settings.blade.php;

```
<form action="{{url('/admin/save-settings')}}" method="post">

{{csrf_field()}}

@if (is_array($settings) || is_object($settings))

@foreach($settings as $setting)

.
.
.

@endforeach
@endif

</form>
```

Route; (under admin prefix)

```
Route::post('/save-settings','AdminController@postSavesettings');
});
```

and Controller;

```
public function postSavesettings(Request $mainsetdata)
{
    unset($mainsetdata['_token']);
    $settings=Settings::where('id',1)->update($mainsetdata->all());

    return view('back.settings')->with('settings',$settings);

}
```

Where do i make mistake ?

Comment: Your url is not correctly displayed you should use {{ url('/admin/save-settings') }} instead of {{ '/admin/save-settings' }}.


And if you named your route, you should do {{ route('route.name') }}

Comment: And `$settings=Settings::where('id',1)` will return one element not an collection !!

Comment: Take a look at your log in the folder `storage/logs` and post the error here.

Comment: @Maraboc Actually Laravel return an Array when using Where.
Also you should use find(1) instead of where.

Comment: @Jerodev How i miss that url.. Thanks, I dont understand somethings. How can i post error there ? and what is the difference between return one element and collection

Answer (score 0):

First see the error logs to find the problem in coding part. If no error found than

Try like this:

```
return view('back.settings',compact('settings'))->with('success','setting update successfully');
```

Answer (score 0):

When change the return below, it worked,

```
return redirect()->back();
```